# CDK deploy neither updating my CoudFormation template nor is it deploying the updates

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I updated cdk-stack.ts file with additional resolvers and updated the directory location for [lamdba](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda) functions.

```
// create a lambda function
    const lambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, `${this.APP_NAME}-function`, {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
      handler:'index.handler',
      code: lambda.Code.asset('dist')
    });
```

[dist dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72YE8.png)

if I do a `cdk diff`, I can see there's difference in the metadata.

```
AWS::Lambda::Function 
 └─ [~] Metadata
     └─ [~] .aws:asset:path:
         ├─ [-] asset.8b3702f0cb9ece01107b448a0829e139592b8c316de111df850555b7a39772d8
         └─ [+] asset.7ca5a346414e4ba91ede1094621c5f2df8293ab7e1d6acd64f712270c62c6ecd
```

But, once deployed I cant see any new events in cloudformation or changes to the deployed lambda function.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: What is the output of cdk deploy?

Comment: From my experience the CloudFormation template isn't updated unless the TypeScript files are built. Did you run `npm run build` before synthing and deploying?

Comment: yea, it seems it was an issue with zipping the dir. it's resolved in v1.3.0. 
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3503